# Never Ending background thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, timertask

I currently have a listview that is populated upon creation from a web server. I want it to either poll the database for updates routinely, or to allow a php script to update it. I would prefer that it be updated by the database, rather than polling.

As far as polling goes I know that I can implement a service or an asyncthread. I also have found the timertask class.

For AsyncThread: Can I have this be recurring continuosly? Would I call the .start method from the

For TimerTask: Is this less efficient than an asyncthread or service?

Also do I need to create the TimerTask inside of a thread? or will it create its own threads?

Comment: Do you understand how webservers work? They're not designed to update the client from the server. There are projects that do that, but webservers are designed to be polled.

Comment: yea I understand as much and had accepted that I would have to poll, but wanted to be sure, since this is an area I am not experienced with

Comment: I'd just like to add that code in a Service still runs in the same thread as the calling Activity. An IntentService as suggested by CommonsWare does run tasks in separate worker threads and is the way to go.

Comment: I know it's a bit late to the party, but for future reader's sake, there is always the option of push notifications. We use a cronjob on our server to run a php script that sends a push notification to all online users every x time.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to turn a server into a client, and a client into a server, is like trying to eat through the wrong orifice. It's fighting against the nature of the original design.

For one thing, you can't rely on your application to be on continuously, not on a phone anyway. Applications on cell phones have low priority. Applications on cell phones have limited energy they can use. Applications on cell phones are also not always going to be connected to the internet.

So for one thing, you'll want to use a Service on its own thread (you can use AsyncTask if you like). Your service will need its own thread so it doesn't block the UI thread waiting for responses. And you'll want to use AlarmManager to wake up or terminate your Service as needed (since your Service is bound to get killed a few times, through no fault of its own).

Comment: I would recommend using an `IntentService` with `AlarmManager`, so the service can get out of RAM when it is not actively delivering value to the user.

Comment: When you say that the service will get killed I understand that, so should I just set an arbitrary length to its alarmmanager? ie. something longer than the rate of polling?      Also the android dev site states that alarmmanager is less efficient than a handler for normal timing operations that don't require an exact time, so why are you guys suggesting that over a handler?

Comment: Stephan, when I say continously I don't mean every millisecond, I mean something like polling every 30 seconds repeatedly, where by continuously that as soon as one polling attempt is complete the timer until the next one starts.

Comment: Is the alarmmanager able to check to see if a service is already running, so that it doesn't spawn a second instance of a service if it has not been killed? Also with regard to my above comment, I mean no disrespect